# Regular expression to replace all url from string but skip one

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have regular expression that's is removing all url from a string but I want to change this and add exception for my site link.

```
$url = 'This is url for example to remove www.somewbsite.com but i want to skip removing this url www.mywebsite.com';  

$no_url = preg_replace("/(https|http|ftp)\:\/\/|([a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|\?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\&\=\#a-z]+)/i", "★", $url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you are replacing with a hard-coded symbol, and you are using a case-insensitive modifier, your regex can be reduced to

```
'~(?:https?|ftp)://|(?:[a-z0-9]+\.)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,4}|\?[a-z0-9]+[&=#a-z]+~i'
```

whatever it means to match. Note that 2 alternatives here were too similar (`[a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}`), they are merged into 1 with the help of an optional non-capturing group (`(?:[a-z0-9]+\.)?`).

Now, if you want to avoid matching a specific pattern, you may use a [SKIP-FAIL technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex): match what you want to preserve and skip it.

```
'~www\.mywebsite\.com(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:https?|ftp)://|(?:[a-z0-9]+\.)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,4}|\?[a-z0-9]+[&=#a-z]+~i'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/McukUq/1).

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Works perfect.